# Angular 6 Reactive Forms Custom Validator Error Displayed from it's OWN data

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a FormArray in a FormGroup and each of the FormArray has multiple FormGroup's and can add them dynamically.

I have a Custom Validator where it checks with all the data in each of the FormArray to validate the repetition of data. **There's an issue with it, the single FormGroup in FormArray is comparing it to all the data in the FormArray and is returning True since the FormGroup exists inside of the FormArray**

StackBlits link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validator-defaultdata

*Problem Steps:* 
**Click on Additional Assignment => Select Position, Department and Location same as the previous row. => You'll see the error, "Same Job data
" => Now change the value of the Position to something else => No Error => Change the value in the Pay Rate input => You see the error, "Same Job data
" > Because it's comparing the changed row to the data from the Form Data which will definitely return True.**

Is there any way to restrict the error from throwing itself when it's checking its own data.?

I'm only checking the similarity between Position, Department, and Location.

```
for (let assign of this.additionalAssign) {
      const fg = new FormGroup({
        "payRate": new FormControl(assign.jobRate, Validators.required),
        "position": new FormControl(assign.position, Validators.required),
        "location": new FormControl(assign.location, Validators.required),
        "department": new FormControl(assign.department, Validators.required)
      }); 
      fg.validator = this.jobDataValidator.bind(this);
      this.addPay.push(fg);
    }
```

Validator:

```
jobDataValidator(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    let value = this.getJobLocDeptValidity(control);
    if(value.length > 0 && control.dirty){
      return {'sameJobData': true};
    }
    return null;
  }

  getJobLocDeptValidity(control: FormControl):any[] {
    let additionalAssignments = this.additionalAssignmentsForm.value.payArray;
    let test = additionalAssignments.filter(item =>  !!control.value.position && item.position === control.value.position && !!control.value.department && item.department === control.value.department && !!control.value.location && item.location === control.value.location);
    return test;
  }
```

Image 1: New Row (3rd) data same as previous one(2nd) => Error Displayed
[image: Same data as previous one]

Image 2: Change the Position select value and the Error Disappears
[image: Position changed and Error Disappears]

Image 3: Enter some number in Pay Rate input and the Error displays again.
[image: Input payrate changes and Error Appears]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked your sample application and did some minor changes in the code. now it is working as expected. Please see on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validator-defaultdata-zxzryh?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.ts).

I have done three changes which are listed below :

1. You don't have any uniqueid on row level, I have added as index of your **'this.addPay'** length. See Line number : 57 and 75.
2. applied condition in the **'getJobLocDeptValidity'** method to check index of current control and filter index should not be same and did some other changes.

Here are the code changes of your getJobLocDepValidity.

```js
 getJobLocDeptValidity(control: FormControl):any[] {
    let additionalAssignments = this.additionalAssignmentsForm.value.payArray;
    let test = additionalAssignments.filter(item => {
if(control.value.index != item.index){
return (item.payRate == control.value.payRate && item.position == control.value.position && item.department == control.value.department && item.location == control.value.location)
}
return false;
    } );
    return test;
  }
```

@Sunil I would suggest, please try to give a correct answer and test it before giving your inputs, So someone can implement easily without any buggy code.

Comment: Hi Ajay, there's a small issue left.  Steps: --->  Add a new Additional Assignment => Have it same data as the previous row => You see the error => Change the previous Row => You still see the error.<----   Is there any way to not display it when the data is not same.????

Comment: I have done the changes in the code and now it is working fine. please check, I have added keypress event on payrate control and call the formgroup method of 'updateValueAndValidity' to refresh the validation. please check line no 91 to 98. Please call the 'updateValidity' method from dropdown change event. if there is any confusion please let me know.

Comment: Hi Ajay, I couldn't find the 'updateValueAndValidity' function, so I made code changes to call my existing validator, 'getJobLocDeptValidity()'. I'm unable to get rid of the error when changing the previous row. Can you please help me over this. Thanks. My updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validator-defaultdata-komxbb

Comment: can you see this working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validator-defaultdata-zxzryh?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.ts , Your code is not updated with my code. please see my stackblitz link.

Comment: Please see line number 95, where I have called 't.updateValueAndValidity();' this is FormGroup Method. Your code is not updated with my code. in your project repository try to do two changes to make it working. 1.replace the line no. 97 with this code : 't.updateValueAndValidity();' and replace line number with this : 'return (item.position == control.value.position && item.department == control.value.department && item.location == control.value.location);
}'.

Comment: Your welcome, Please let me know if you face any other problem in this.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation looks perfectly fine except the check condition. Since you don't have any unique id for row its difficult to match if the record is existing one or now.

However you are lucky enough to have reference of all required object. You can check if the Object matched or not.

Just add one more condition in validation part

```
control !== item
```

Below is the changed code -

```
  getJobLocDeptValidity(control: FormControl):any[] {

    let additionalAssignments = this.additionalAssignmentsForm.value.payArray;
    let test = additionalAssignments.filter(item =>  
    control !== item && !!control.value.position && item.position === control.value.position && !!control.value.department && item.department === control.value.department && !!control.value.location && item.location === control.value.location);
    return test;
  }
```

### Update

Since you have `index` and per your comment, below check works.

```
control.index !== item.i
```

Comment: Had to add index and then check control.index !== item.index. Then it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked for you, Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try excluding the payRate value from the validator like so:

```
jobDataValidator(control: FormControl): {[s: string]: boolean} {
    let value = this.getJobLocDeptValidity(control);
    if(value.length > 0 && control.dirty  && !control.value.payRate){
      return {'sameJobData': true};
    }
    return null;
  }
```